# BTT SKR 1.4 Turbo SPI setup

Tags: creality-ender-5

Can anyone confirm that on the SKR 1.4 Turbo you don’t need any of the jumper wires to enable SPI mode? Like you would do on the 1.3 variant?
As I have searched and cannot seem to find any reference to using linking wires.
Also, do you have to manually adjust the output of each driver by the potentiometer? As adjusting the in the screen doesn’t seem to do anything?
Any help in this regard would be most appreciated.
Paul

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You don't need jumper wires, communications is done through the jumpers and the board directly.

What drivers are you using?

Comment: On the Xand Y I’m using the tmc2130 and on the z I’m using tmc5160

Comment: That'll work just fine. No need to adjust the pot on the drivers. Enable "TMC_DEBUG" in your firmware. You will be able to use "M122" to check if the driver communication works fine and if the currents are changing as expected.